# EmitMapper's List Mapping Issue with Collections

Tags: c#, exception, mapping, mapper, emitmapper

The source class:

```
public class Post
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="nvarchar")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="varchar")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string UrlName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="ntext")]
    public string Excerpt { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="ntext")]
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime PostedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

the destination class

```
public class Post : Model
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlName { get; set; }
    public string Excerpt { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastCommentedTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I try using EmitMapper to map from each other; when mapping from source to desction, here is the code sample：

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ShouleMapEntityToModel()
    {
        Post eP = new Post();
        eP.ID = 2;
        eP.Comments = new List<Comment>();

        eP.Comments.Add(new Comment()
            {
                ID = 2,
                Author = "derek"
            });

        var mP = eP.Map<Post, mBlog.Core.Models.Post>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(mP);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, mP.Comments.Count());
    }
```

and I got an exception,

Test method mBlog.Test.EmitMapperTest.ShouleMapEntityToModel threw exception: 
System.Exception: Constructor for types [] not found in System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[mBlog.Core.Models.Post, mBlog.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Comment: Is Map an extension to Post? If so it would be useful to give it a look to see how you create the mapper

Comment: An easy fix is to put a default constructor and initialize the lists yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I have found the solution. Don't user Lists for your destination object. If you use simple arrays in your mBlog.Core.Models.Post object you should get a nicely filled object. So your destination class should look like:

```
public class Post : Model
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlName { get; set; }
    public string Excerpt { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastCommentedTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    public Category[] Category { get; set; }
    public Comment[] Comments { get; set; }
    public Tag[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: though it works, but it doesn't fix the problem of EmitMapper. Anyway I've turn back to AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how to handle IEnumerable to IEnumerable: [EmitMapper and List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40220655/7064571)

I believe that can be applied to this case too. Take a look:

> This can be done creating a custom class, implementing the interface "ICustomConverterProvider" and adding a ConvertGeneric to the "DefaultMapConfig".
>
> Looking on the source code of EmitMapper, i found a class named "ArraysConverterProvider", which is the default generic converter from ICollections to Arrays.
>
> Adapting the code from this class to work with IEnumerable
>   collections:
>
> ```
> class GenericIEnumerableConverterProvider : ICustomConverterProvider
>     {
>       public CustomConverterDescriptor GetCustomConverterDescr(
>             Type from,
>             Type to,
>             MapConfigBaseImpl mappingConfig)
>         {
>             var tFromTypeArgs = DefaultCustomConverterProvider.GetGenericArguments(from);
>             var tToTypeArgs = DefaultCustomConverterProvider.GetGenericArguments(to);
>             if (tFromTypeArgs == null || tToTypeArgs == null || tFromTypeArgs.Length != 1 || tToTypeArgs.Length != 1)
>             {
>                 return null;
>             }
>             var tFrom = tFromTypeArgs[0];
>             var tTo = tToTypeArgs[0];
>             if (tFrom == tTo && (tFrom.IsValueType || mappingConfig.GetRootMappingOperation(tFrom, tTo).ShallowCopy))
>            {
>                return new CustomConverterDescriptor
>                 {
>                     ConversionMethodName = "Convert",
>                     ConverterImplementation = typeof(GenericIEnumerableConverter_OneTypes<>),
>                     ConverterClassTypeArguments = new[] { tFrom }
>                 };
>             }
>
>             return new CustomConverterDescriptor
>             {
>                 ConversionMethodName = "Convert",
>                 ConverterImplementation = typeof(GenericIEnumerableConverter_DifferentTypes<,>),
>                 ConverterClassTypeArguments = new[] { tFrom, tTo }
>             }; 
>         }
>     }
>
>
> class GenericIEnumerableConverter_DifferentTypes<TFrom, TTo> : ICustomConverter
>     {
>         private Func<TFrom, TTo> _converter;
>         public IEnumerable<TTo> Convert(IEnumerable<TFrom> from, object state)
>         {
>             if (from == null)
>             {
>                 return null;
>             } 
>
>             TTo[] result = new TTo[from.Count()];
>             int idx = 0;
>             foreach (var f in from)
>             {
>                 result[idx++] = _converter(f);
>             }
>
>             return result;
>         } 
>
>         public void Initialize(Type from, Type to, MapConfigBaseImpl mappingConfig)
>         {
>             var staticConverters = mappingConfig.GetStaticConvertersManager() ?? StaticConvertersManager.DefaultInstance;
>
>             var staticConverterMethod = staticConverters.GetStaticConverter(typeof(TFrom), typeof(TTo));
>
>            if (staticConverterMethod != null)
>             {
>                 _converter = (Func<TFrom, TTo>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
>                     typeof(Func<TFrom, TTo>),
>                     null,
>                     staticConverterMethod
>                 );
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 _subMapper = ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapperImpl(typeof(TFrom), typeof(TTo), mappingConfig);
>
>                 _converter = ConverterBySubmapper;
>             }
>         } 
>
>         ObjectsMapperBaseImpl _subMapper;
>
>         private TTo ConverterBySubmapper(TFrom from)
>         {
>             return (TTo)_subMapper.Map(from);
>         }
>     }
>
>
> class GenericIEnumerableConverter_OneTypes<T>
>     {
>
>         public IEnumerable<T> Convert(IEnumerable<T> from, object state)
>         {
>             if (from == null)
>           {
>                 return null;
>             }
>
>             return from;
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> This code is just a copy with a minimum of adaptation as possible and
>   can be applyed to objects with many levels of hierarchy.
>
> You can use the above code with the following command:
>
> ```
>   new DefaultMapConfig().ConvertGeneric(
>     typeof(IEnumerable<>),
>     typeof(IEnumerable<>),
>     new GenericIEnumerableConverterProvider());
> ```
>
> This saved my day and I hope to save yours too! hehehe